# How to play sound from microphone byte array in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays, playback, microphone

I'm trying to play sound from ByteArray captured from the microphone and I'm expecting to hear the sound from the microphone but what I get is only random, distorted sound. This is the code that I'm using now :

```
var playBa:ByteArray;

var player:Sound = new Sound();
sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playMic);
sound.play();

var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone();
mic.gain = 100;
mic.rate = 44;
mic.setSilenceLevel(0, 4000);
mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, onMicSample);

function playMic(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    if (playBa != null) e.data.writeBytes(playBa, 0, playBa.length);
}

function onMicSample(e:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    playBa = e.data;
    playBa.position = 0;
    player.play();
}
```

And after a few seconds of distorted sounds, this is what I got on the Output Window:

```
RangeError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
at flash.media::Sound/play()
at vclass_fla::MainTimeline/onMicSample()
```

Please help me. I'm a totally new to AS3 and here. Any help are highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Microphones are very sensitive. You need to adjust moderate settings like shown below. Also, if speakers are closer to microphone the sound get looped.

```
var myMic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(); // detect microphone
myMic.gain = 50;
myMic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
myMic.setLoopBack(true);
myMic.setSilenceLevel(50, 1000);
```

To more about Sound Capturing try this,
 [Capturing microphone sound data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d1d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d0b)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but the result is still the same. What I need is to get the byte array from the microphone and then send it to the server while using the same byte array, play the byte array to the Sound class.

Comment: I believe I have shown how the "sound" object is created. Look at the code above. player is the sound object.

Comment: what is that sound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playMic);? I think it should be "player" instead of "sound". Check your code first.

Comment: Ahh yeah... that was my mistake.. ok wait, it's correct here.. I just mistyped the code above. I try with the link you give first.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that sample data event requires blocks of 2048 to 8192 samples. If the samples recorded by microphone at the call of "playMic" the runtime throw "RangeError: Error #2004...".

```
function playMic(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    trace("sample event");
    for (var ii:uint = 0; ii < 8192 && playBa.bytesAvailable > 0 ; ii++)
    {
        var n1:Number = playBa.readFloat();
        //trace(n1);
        event.data.writeFloat(n1);
        event.data.writeFloat(n1);
        if(playBa.bytesAvailable == 0)
        {
            trace("data_finished");
            break;
        }
    }

}
```